# ubuntu 18.04, R 3.5.0 , library TMB , installation warnings and fatal error during execution

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04, tmb

fresh new install of ubuntu 18.04. -> ok

R 3.5.0 installed from this repo:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

with secure apt key added by:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

R installed correctly and working even launched from rstudio.
Trying to install `TMB` library, installation command from R console or terminal R in super user mode with this command (tried both and removed one before trying the second, so no possible conflict between user libraries and R libraries):

```
install.packages("TMB",type = "source")
```

the installation starts, 
it install dependant packages (Rcpp,RcppEigen etcetera).

**during the installation/compiling of exactly RcppEigen the console starts to kicks like 10000 line of warnings (like if is missing some compiler link)**, this is the first line of which it deviates from normal installation:

```
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (Rcpp)
* installing *source* package ‘RcppEigen’ ...
** package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-O3QT2W/r-base-3.5.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
In file included from ../inst/include/Eigen/Core:388:0,
                 from ../inst/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from RcppEigen.cpp:22:
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:60:39: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128 {aka __vector(4) float}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
 template<> struct is_arithmetic<__m128>  { enum { value = true }; };
                                       ^
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:61:40: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128i{aka __vector(2) long long int}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
 template<> struct is_arithmetic<__m128i> { enum { value = true }; };
                                        ^
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:62:40: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128d{aka __vector(2) double}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
 template<> struct is_arithmetic<__m128d> { enum { value = true }; };
                                        ^
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:161:43: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::Packet4f {aka __vector(4) float}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
 template<> struct unpacket_traits<Packet4f> { typedef float  type; enum {size=4, alignment=Aligned16}; typedef Packet4f half; };
```

these are the last lines of the install.package("TMB") command:

```
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type {aka __vector(4) double}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
                      >::type PacketReturnType;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >, -1, -1, false>, -1, -1, false>, 1, -1, false> >, 0>’:
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:478:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >, -1, -1, false>, -1, -1, false>, 1, -1, false> >, 2>’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >, -1, -1, false>, -1, -1, false>, 1, -1, false> > >’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >, -1, -1, false>, -1, -1, false>, 1, -1, false> > >’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Transpose.h:115:37:   required from ‘class Eigen::TransposeImpl<const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >, -1, -1, false>, -1, -1, false>, 1, -1, false>, Eigen::Dense>’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Transpose.h:52:37:   required from ‘class Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >, -1, -1, false>, -1, -1, false>, 1, -1, false> >’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/ProductEvaluators.h:552:40:   [ skipping 22 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:816:7:   required from ‘void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_init1(const Eigen::DenseBase<ElseDerived>&) [with T = Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; OtherDerived = Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:296:31:   required from ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const T&) [with T = Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; _Scalar = double; int _Rows = -1; int _Cols = -1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = -1; int _MaxCols = -1]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/tmbutils/vector.hpp:93:22:   required from ‘tmbutils::matrix<Type>::matrix(T1) [with T1 = Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; Type = double]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/expm.hpp:36:14:   required from ‘atomic::Block<Type> atomic::Block<Type>::inverse() [with Type = double]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/expm.hpp:180:17:   required from ‘matrix_pade atomic::expm(matrix_pade) [with matrix_pade = atomic::nestedTriangle<0>]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/expm.hpp:192:52:   required from here`
```

the last line of output from install.packages("TMB",type="source") is:

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o simple.so simple.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
Build time 16.121 seconds

* DONE (TMB)
```

the installation seems to finish (console gives * DOME(TMB) at the end), but running a basic example of TMB (linear regression) gives fatal R session error.

example in R code:

```
tmb_model <- "
// linear regression
#include <TMB.hpp>

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() () {
// data:
DATA_VECTOR(x);
DATA_VECTOR(y);

// parameters:
PARAMETER(a); // intercept
PARAMETER(b); // slope
PARAMETER(log_sigma); // log(residual SD)
// we fit sigma on a log scale to keep it > 0

// procedures: (transformed parameters)
Type sigma = exp(log_sigma);

int n = y.size(); // get number of data points to loop over

Type nll = 0.0; // initialize negative log likelihood

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ // C++ starts loops at 0!
// get negative log likelihood (last argument is log = TRUE)
nll -= dnorm(y[i], a + b * x[i], sigma, true);
}

return nll;
}"
write(tmb_model, file = "regression.cpp")
library(TMB)
compile("regression.cpp")
```

using TMB::compile gives tons of warnings (these are the last worning + gcc line output):

```
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type {aka __vector(4) double}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
                      >::type PacketReturnType;
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:436:0,
                 from /home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/TMB.hpp:53,
                 from regression.cpp:3:
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h: In instantiation of ‘struct Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 1, -1, false> >’:
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:730:20:   required from ‘void Eigen::internal::call_dense_assignment_loop(DstXprType&, const SrcXprType&, const Functor&) [with DstXprType = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>; SrcXprType = Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 1, -1, false>; Functor = Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:879:31:   required from ‘static void Eigen::internal::Assignment<DstXprType, SrcXprType, Functor, Eigen::internal::Dense2Dense, Weak>::run(DstXprType&, const SrcXprType&, const Functor&) [with DstXprType = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>; SrcXprType = Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 1, -1, false>; Functor = Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>; Weak = void]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:836:49:   required from ‘void Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias(Dst&, const Src&, const Func&) [with Dst = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>; Src = Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 1, -1, false>; Func = Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:804:27:   required from ‘void Eigen::internal::call_assignment(Dst&, const Src&, const Func&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(! Eigen::internal::evaluator_assume_aliasing<Src>::value), void*>::type) [with Dst = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>; Src = Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 1, -1, false>; Func = Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>; typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(! Eigen::internal::evaluator_assume_aliasing<Src>::value), void*>::type = void*]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:782:18:   required from ‘void Eigen::internal::call_assignment(Dst&, const Src&) [with Dst = Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false>; Src = Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 1, -1, false>]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h:66:28:   [ skipping 26 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:816:7:   required from ‘void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_init1(const Eigen::DenseBase<ElseDerived>&) [with T = Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; OtherDerived = Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:296:31:   required from ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const T&) [with T = Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; _Scalar = double; int _Rows = -1; int _Cols = -1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = -1; int _MaxCols = -1]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/tmbutils/vector.hpp:93:22:   required from ‘tmbutils::matrix<Type>::matrix(T1) [with T1 = Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; Type = double]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/expm.hpp:36:14:   required from ‘atomic::Block<Type> atomic::Block<Type>::inverse() [with Type = double]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/expm.hpp:180:17:   required from ‘matrix_pade atomic::expm(matrix_pade) [with matrix_pade = atomic::nestedTriangle<0>]’
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/TMB/include/expm.hpp:192:52:   required from here
/home/alberto/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h:960:8: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type {aka __vector(4) double}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
   enum {
        ^
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o regression.so regression.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
[1] 0
```

During execution of this R code it gives me immediately fatal error on rstudio (R console), exactly taken from TMB examples:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(20, 1, 10)
y <- rnorm(20, mean = 1.8 + 2.4 * x, sd = exp(0.3))
plot(x, y)
obj <- MakeADFun(
  data = list(x = x, y = y), 
  parameters = list(a = 0, b = 0, log_sigma = 0),
  DLL = "regression")
opt <- nlminb(start = obj$par, obj = obj$fn, gr = obj$gr)
rep <- sdreport(obj)
```

compiler:

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
```

~.R/Makevars (something touched before for RcppArmadillo, maybe it is my fault and the error is here on CXXFLAGS):

```
CFLAGS= -O -mtune=native
CXXFLAGS= -O2 -mtune=native -march=native -pthread -fopenmp $(BLAS_LIBS) $(LAPACK_LIBS)
FFLAGS=-g -O -mtune=native
FCFLAGS=-g -O -mtune=native
```

Edit(myself)
I try the RcppEigen example at: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.eigen.html
it runs ok, pushing many warnings (that normally don't occur with Rcpp), calling `sourceCpp(file="input.cc")`, it compile and execute correctly.

I try the first example found on TMB at https://github.com/nwfsc-assess/geostatistical_delta-GLMM/wiki/Steps-to-install-TMB
it gives me :

```
0 regions found.
Using 8 threads
TMB has received an error from Eigen. The following condition was not met:
index >= 0 && index < size()
Please check your matrix-vector bounds etc., or run your program through a debugger.
```

before crashing

Comment: What is your actual question? Compiler _warnings_ (from newer compilers) are just what they say: a "warning".  Noisy, a little irritating, but harmless.

Comment: If you have an issue with TMB (as it seems) maybe post an issue at their [GitHub repo issue page](https://github.com/kaskr/adcomp/issues) just like their [DESCRIPTION file suggests](https://github.com/kaskr/adcomp/blob/master/TMB/DESCRIPTION#L41) ?

Comment: thank you for reply, im not scared by the warnings as compilation during installation terminate correctly. But as I try the example proposed and gives fatal error, I don't know if the problem is RcppEigen (as is the first which kick out warnings) or TMB as the warnings made by compiling TMB packet refers to TMB and some RcppEigen included files.. I follow your indication and ask into github

Comment: Take the `tar.gz` from CRAN. Run `R CMD check` on it.  If that passes for RcppEigen (as it should) then you know it is not RcppEigen.  Ditto for TMB.

Comment: I edited the question, tried RcppEigen alone with his basic example at http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.eigen.html and it works (compile and run correctly). during compilation using sourceCpp it kicks the same warnings, using sourceCpp on another input with only Rcpp and RcppArmadillo inside (no call to RcppEigen methods or class/object) doesn't give me any warning

Comment: So I guess we can edit the `rcpp` tag away, and you have a problem "just" with `TMB`.  Sometimes you just need to recompiled all pieces, so maybe try reinstalling `TMB` (and possibly other [compiled] dependencies it has).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

1) to avoid noisy warnings output, add the flag

```
-Wno-ignored-attributes
```

2) to avoid runtime error on adfun call, remove the flag

```
-fopenmp
```

before compiling the objective function **IF** the model (C++ code of `objective_function<Type>::operator()`) doesn't use **openMP** (example `#pragma omp` *something*).

source (I ask here): https://github.com/kaskr/adcomp/issues/277

Answer (score 0):

looks like you may not have the Eigen dev package installed (since is it is fresh ubuntu install) 
Have you tried

```
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```

looks like you can also install precompiled binary the package via

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcppeigen
```

apparently rcppeigen may require a lot of ram to compile and fails on some machines with little ram.

Comment: Wrong answer.  Use Eigen via the RcppEigen package.

Comment: thank you for the input. I tried (installed as libeigen3-dev missed), then reinstall R as 'apt install r-base-dev' this time, reinstalled the packages Rcpp, TMB with dependancies =TRUE option and from source, it changes nothing, identical warnings. I try even to reinstall RcppEigen and gives me the same warnings

Comment: reply to the edit: it say he can not install it as it depends on r-api-3.4...but maybe I need to add another repo like deb https://<my.favorite.ubuntu.mirror>/ bionic-backports main restricted universe